# Mapinfo Runtime error when called from PowerBuilder

Tags: mapinfo

When I am trying to call MapInfo from my PowerBuilder application, with map info pro(full) version "Open table" command is working fine but with mapinfo runtime(proviewer) "Open table"  is crashing for the below syntax saying error calling external object.

```
MIOleObject.application.Do("Open Table 'C:\Jail\DataDir\GcuPerm.tab' as Zones Interactive")
```

Please suggest me what could be the problem?

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: The error Message is " Error calling External object function do at line XXX in open event of object XXX"

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but aren't Runtime and ProViewer different entities? If its ProViewer that you're using, thats very limited - does it even support what you're trying to do?

Comment: You are correct: Proviewer can't be automated.

Answer (score 1):

MapBasic strings must use double quotes.

Are you rally sure you want to use the `Interactive` option?

```
MIOleObject.Application.Do("Open Table ~"C:\Jail\DataDir\GcuPerm.tab~" as Zones")
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.                                         
I tried with double quotes but no luck. Yes,I want to use Interactive option because i am performing further actions using these maps. 
The current code is working absolutely fine with Mapinfo full version but it doesnt work with runtime version. Also, while connecting to Runtime version MIOleObject.ConnectToNewObject("MapInfo.Runtime") works fine but MIOleObject.ConnectToNewObject("MapInfo.Application") is throwing an error. 

please let me know what other options can i try.

Comment: It's possible that the runtime does not support `Interactive`.

Comment: Can u please let me know What other options can be used? I tried with   MIOleObject.Application.Do("Open Table ~"C:\Jail\DataDir\GcuPerm.tab~" as Zones")  But,it dint work either..